# python error syntaxerror 'return' outside function

Tags: python

Getting syntax error `'return' outside function` while running below code.

```
# Make the request to publish and check status code 

    print("\tUploading...") 
    server_response = requests.post(publish_url, data=payload,  
                                    headers={'x-tableau-auth': auth_token, 'content-type': content_type}) 
    _check_status(server_response, 201) 
    return
```

Comment: Which part of error you've received is unclear to you? What do you expect `return` will do when it's used outside of function?

Comment: Did you also place `return` outside the code in purpose? XD

Comment: Its a readymade script- got it from Github. Please validate the indentation. Thanks.

Comment: publish_url = server + "/api/{0}/sites/{1}/workbooks".format(VERSION, site_id) 
  publish_url += "?workbookType={0}&overwrite=true".format(file_extension) 


 # Make the request to publish and check status code 

  print("\tUploading...") 
  server_response = requests.post(publish_url, data=payload,  
          headers={'x-tableau-auth': auth_token, 'content-type': content_type}) 
  _check_status(server_response, 201) 
return

Comment: Edit the question and post relevant code there. And take special care formatting and indenting the code correctly (specially because you are using python)

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly says that you are using `return` outside a function.

Since your code is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we will have to guess what's happening.

Basically there can be two cases:

1. Your `return` instruction is incorrectly indented. You can fix it by indenting the instruction until it falls inside the function you want to return from.

Example:

```
def foo:
    # do something inside the function 
    # ...

    return     # notice the indentation
```

2. Your code has not function at all (like the code you posted), so the use of `return` is incorrect. (This is unlikely since you just copied/pasted the code from Github, however it's also a possibility).

**PD**: By the way, if you use `return` and you don't actually return anything (like the code you posted) you can just get rid of the instruction. The function will automatically return when it reaches the end.